# Rails ActiveRecord: Inserting text containing unprintable/weird characters

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord, sanitize

I am inserting some text from scraped web into my database. some of the fields in the string have unprintable/weird characters. For example,

```
if text is "C__O__?__P__L__E__T__E", 
then the text in the database is stored only as "C__O__"
```

I know about h(), strip_tags()... sanitize, ... etc etc. But I do not want to sanitize this SQL. The activerecord logs the SQL correctly, and when run in phpMySQL, the query is executed correctly. something happens between the SQL query generation and it being executed.

Help is much appreciated.

Comment: The ? is the parameter substitution character; it should only happen if you're using it in your query text rather than as a parameter.  Please amend your question to give an example of exactly what you're doing.

Comment: Yes, show us an example of the code which is causing the problem

Comment: -1 Questions needs clarifications.  If you're calling the SQL through normal find methods, Rails does a brilliant job substituting the ?.  If you are manually just injecting the values into the query using string append this could be a problem.  Gareth and womble's comments need to be addressed.

Comment: What is the statement you run? SomeModel.create(..)?

Comment: You say you don't want to sanitize the SQL, but if ActiveRecord is treating ? as a substitution character, then you *are* sanitizing it, and that's causing your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hmmmm.. using CGI escape, I found out that the character coming in the system is not what I expected it to be. It is not a question mark (%3F) but a question mark (%D5).

```
C__%D5__M__P__L__%80___T__%80__
C__%3F__M__P__L__%3F___T__%3F__
```

***Eventually I gsubbed out the non-printable characters before saving.***

```
gsub(/[^[:print:]]/, '')
```

**Only after removing the invalid characters in my string, was I able to save the item properly.
None of the other solutions worked, partially because the problem was not understood clearly upfront.**

Answer (score 1):

Just replace the question mark in the string with a string containing a question mark, I haven't found any other way either:

["C__O__?__P__L__E__T__E", '?']

works perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Can you escape the question mark using "\?"?

Answer (score 0):

I know this is way late, but I ran into the same problem when we were trying to process a file as UTF-8 that actually used the ISO-8859-1 character encoding. I suspect you had a similar issue in your scraping where you assumed the wrong encoding and it ended up causing things to fail.